# plot from a dataframe containing lists as column values

Tags: r, ggplot2, tibble

I have been messing using the purrr package and now have a unique problem. I want to plot the dataframe where the values are list containing values inside column.

**Structure:**

```
a b x           y
1 1 c(1,2,3,4) c(4,5,6,7)
1 2 c(1,2,3,4) c(5.4,6,6.5,7)
```

**Attempted Solution:**

```
library("tidyverse")

# Define a named list of parameter values
temp = list(a = seq(1,5,1),
           b = seq(0.1,3,1)) %>% cross_df()

# create two new columns
x <- seq(1,5,0.1)
y <- 2.3 * x

# add these as a list
temp$x <- list(x)
temp$y <- list(y)

ggplot(data=temp, aes(x=unlist(x),y=unlist(y),color=a)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("Plot of Y vs. X shown by colour of a")
```

**Error:**

1. *Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (15): x, y, colour* using unlist
2. *Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale* when not using unlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate the list elements into separate rows which can be done using `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)

temp %>%
  unnest() %>%
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x,y,color=a) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("Plot of Y vs. X shown by colour of a")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!